# What meaning does exp function have?

Tags: activation-function, softmax

Is there any problem that solution(or algorithm) would be exp function?

Let's say f(x)=2^x.

It's an answer of a problem when you would like to know how many pieces would be made when you fold a paper for x times.

Then, what for exp function?

exp function can also be described as

[image]

or

[image]

So there would be some problem that would suit for this answer.

I just would like to picture the meaning of exp function, so if you have other explanation for understanding it, it's welcome.

Comment: The [wikipedia page for $e$ has a section for the applications of the number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Applications), with one of them being continuously compounding interest rates.

Comment: Thanks Oxbowerce. But that is a definition of e. I'm asking about exp().

Comment: I might be understanding your question wrong, but is that not described on the example of interest rates. You can use $e^{Rt}$ (i.e. exp(Rt)) to calculate the interest rate over a specific time if the interest is compounded continuously.